# NSPredicate to compare identical string arrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

Is it possible to use nspredicate to compare whether one NSArray is exactly equal  to another NSArray of strings? I need this dome via predicates because of its possible I will add this predicate to a compound predicate.

The Array I am comparing against is a property of an NSDictionary.

So the answer was a mixture of both, I did use the predicatewithformat but got creative in the string inside, inspired by @akashivskyy and @avi

```
  [predicatesArray addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY dynamic.values == %@", arr]];
```

Comment: Why would you use a predicate to see if two arrays are equal?

Comment: I have a number of filtering operations that I am using a compound nspredicate for.

Comment: FYI, I edited the answer to use a format string predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** As (partially) suggested by [Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085011/avi), you may use the equality predicate:

```
NSArray *otherArray = @[ @"foo", @"bar" ];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self == %@", otherArray];

[predicate evaluateWithObject:@[ @"foo", @"bar" ]]; // YES
[predicate evaluateWithObject:@[ @"baz", @"qux" ]]; // NO
```

Alternatively, and if you have any trouble with format string in the future, you may always use a block predicate to perform your own logic:

```
NSArray *otherArray = @[ @"foo", @"bar" ];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^(NSArray *evaluatedArray, NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedArray isEqualToArray:otherArray];
}];

// use the predicate
```

Comment: that kinda did the job, I should've clarified more, the NSArray I am comparing against is a property of another NSDictionary, how can I sue your answer to access that?

Comment: You can also do `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == %@", array1, array2]`.

Comment: @Avi: Your version requires both `array1` and `array2` to be declared outside. But using `self` will do the trick, thanks for suggestion!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to get into the details of how to reference the data and stuff.  The important bit was to demonstrate that `==` works just fine for arrays, so there's no need to get fancy.

Comment: So the answer was a mixture of both, I did use the predicatewithformat but got creative in the string inside.